# I have this code, when submited the form dont refresh, someone know how refresh after submit on october cms?

Tags: forms, octobercms

```
<form data-request="onSend" data-request-update="'{{ __SELF__}}::attbanco': '#banco' "
  data-request-flash  >

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Nome: </td> <td ><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Idade: </td> <td ><input type="number" id="idade" name="idade" value="{{usuario.idade}}"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Telefone: </td> <td ><input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" value="{{usuario.telefone}}"></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<button type="submit" >Enviar</button>

<input type="hidden" value="{{usuario.id}}" name="id">
```

this code work, saves the values on database, but i need manually refresh page to see the result on my
screen, someone know how refresh after submit?
Please, explain most simple possible, i am newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is to put the form in a partial and update it when the form is submitted.

Replace your form with this:

```
<div id="specialForm">
{% partial __SELF__~"::specialForm" %}
</div>
```

Create a partial to describe the form; I used specialForm. It should reload the form and clear the content.

```
<form data-request="onSend" data-request-update="'{{ __SELF__}}::attbanco': '#banco', '{{ __SELF__ }}::specialForm': '#specialForm' "
  data-request-flash  >

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Nome: </td> <td ><input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Idade: </td> <td ><input type="number" id="idade" name="idade" value="{{usuario.idade}}"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Telefone: </td> <td ><input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" value="{{usuario.telefone}}"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <button type="submit" >Enviar</button>

    <input type="hidden" value="{{usuario.id}}" name="id">

</form>
```